# Segmentation fault when calling a virtual function from an object of the base class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, lldb, virtual-functions

I am getting a segmentation fault (see bottom of the post for the debugger report) when attempting to call a virtual function from an object. I have read every stackoverflow answer and every web article I have found, but none have seemed to address or solve the problem at hand.

See the below code (which mimics my code structure) as an example:

Class declarations.

```
class A{
public:
    A();
    virtual void foo();
};

class B : A{
public:
    B();
};

class C : B{
public:
    C();
    virtual void foo();
};
```

Class implementations.

```
B::B() : A(){

}

C::C() : B(){

}

void A::foo(){

}

void C::foo(){
    // Code specific to class C
}
```

Function where the seg fault is occurring (the vector declaration is here for reference and is declared and used elsewhere).

```
std::vector<B*>* vec = new std::vector<B*>();

void bar(){
    if(vec){
        for(auto it = vec->begin(); it != vec->end(); it++){
            if((*it)){ 
                printf("*it is not null\n");
                (*it)->foo();
                printf("Called B::foo()\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The seg fault occurs at the call to `foo()` from `*it`.
I have verified that `*it` is not null as the first debug message is being printed and `vec` does indeed have contain elements of type `C`. I added debug messages to C::foo() so I would know when it gets called but it never does and the second debug message in `bar()` is not printed.

What could be causing the seg fault?

The LLDB error report:

> Process 24504 stopped
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x19134f, 0x0000000000000000, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x0)
>
> frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
>
> error: memory read failed for 0x0

**EDIT:**
Test case: https://gist.github.com/SamTebbs33/5fe56879dc6a423842ad

For some reason the above test case works, even though it reflects my code structure.

**EDIT 2:**
After using Valgrind, I get the following report: https://gist.github.com/SamTebbs33/469eefda95a5006abf64

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  (FWIW here's an example that appears to work fine: http://ideone.com/p4WZO3.)

Comment: it's more helpful if you could post a minimum compilable example of the problem (a complete source file that we can cut and paste). If you do that I expect the problem will become obvious anyway.

Comment: @RichardHodges I will do so

Comment: @RichardHodges I have made the test-case: https://gist.github.com/SamTebbs33/5fe56879dc6a423842ad

For some reason, even thigh this example reflects my code structure, the test case works.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Comment: Your test case doesn't fail at all. What makes you so certain just because it is non-null it is still a *valid* object pointer? For all we know (as we don't have your *real* code nor a reproducible facsimile) you have a dangling pointer in that vector, a corrupt vector, the object itself may be corrupt, etc.. Did you run this through Valgrind ?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 this was expected. the problem is somewhere else in your code. re-factor the code into smaller, testable chunks and for goodness sake use unique_ptr, shared_ptr or reference_wrapper when storing polymorphic objects in containers. There is no reason to ever use raw pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have updated the question with the report form Valigrind. I will carry on with some debugging.

Comment: @RichardHodges I will give that try and so some more debugging.

Comment: "Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0" - that certainly doesn't look healthy.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 are you aware that it is possible that when you trashed your memory somewhere else in your program, the resulting crash can happen almost randomly almost everywhere in your program?

Comment: @Greenflow What could cause such a memory corruption then? I'm not doing anything weird or wacky in my code, just normal constructor invocations with "new" etc.

Comment: I don't know what you do. You use 'new', which means you have a certain opportunity to make mistakes, which corrupt your memory. I just wanted to make you aware that some of those bugs can manifest themselves much later than they happen and at seemingly totally unrelated places. This might be the case here since the piece of code you have shown us is perfectly fine. Not that what you have given us looks particularly complete to really say that.

Comment: @Greenflow I tried calling a function that was declared and implemented in class C (one that isn't override) and no seg fault was thrown. So the seg fault is only occurring when calling an overrided virtual function.

Comment: Means nothing. **IF** you corrupt your memory, the resulting crash might happen later, at another place, or even never if you change your code. The memory layout changes and instead of corrupting the code of a function or important data, perhaps only the color of a pixel in an embedded image changes and you will never notice it. That's the problem with memory corruption: The results can be fairly unpredictable. Not saying that is your problem.

Answer (score -1):

What I would try is dynamic casting to C pointer:

```
if ((*it)) {
    printf("*it is not null\n");
    dynamic_cast<C*>(*it)->foo();
    printf("Called B::foo()\n");
}
```

as there is no other obvious reason of segfault.